# R Shiny : Error in If - Argument is of length zerp

Tags: r, shiny

I am facing a really weird error in R Shiny.
I have a dropdown filter which shows the type of date - Due Date, Payment Date and GL Date.
Based on the type of date from the drop down - I have date range selectors respectively for each of these mentioned above.

UI code is as below :

```
output$select_DateType <- renderUI({
  selectInput("date_type","Select Date Type", choices=c("Due Date","GL Date","Payment Date"),selected = "Due Date")
})


output$daterange_due <- renderUI({
  
  x<-reactive({req(input$date_type)})
  y <- x()
 
  if(y == "Due Date"){
     dateRangeInput(inputId = "duedate",label="Due date range",start = min(mydata             ()$duedate),end=max(mydata()$duedate),separator="-")
  } else if(y == "GL Date"){
    dateRangeInput(inputId = "gldate",label="GL date range",start = min(mydata()$gldate          ),end=max(mydata()$gldate),separator="-")

  } else {
    dateRangeInput(inputId = "paydate",label="Payment date range",start = min(mydata             ()$paydate),end=max(mydata()$paydate),separator="-") }
  
})
```

These are used to calculate a lot of other values wherein the date ranges are used to filter the dataset.

Server code

output$dues <- renderValueBox({

x<-reactive({req(input$date_type)})
y<-x()

if(y == "Due Date"){
mydata <- mydata()%>%filter(duedate >= input$duedate[1] & duedate <= input$duedate[2])

valueBox(subtitle = "Total Spend",prettyNum(round(sum(as.numeric(mydata$invamt.base/1000000),na.rm = TRUE),2),big.mark=","),color = "navy", width = 4)
}else if(y == "GL Date"){
mydata <- mydata()%>%filter(gldate >= input$gldate[1] & duedate <= input$gldate[2])

```
valueBox(subtitle = "Total Spend",prettyNum(round(sum(as.numeric(mydata$invamt.base/1000000),na.rm = TRUE),2),big.mark=","),color = "navy", width = 4) 
}else {
mydata <- mydata()%>%filter(paydate >= input$paydate[1] & duedate <= input$paydate[2])

mydata$paydate <- as.numeric(mydata$paydate)
mydata$paydate[is.na(mydata$paydate)] <- 0

valueBox(subtitle = "Total Spend",prettyNum(round(sum(as.numeric(mydata$invamt.base/1000000),na.rm = TRUE),2),big.mark=","),color = "navy", width = 4) }
```

})

There are about 20 such calculations:
What happens is that , when I launch the app it gives me an error in some or all of the value boxes as:
Error in if argument of length is zero.

Also, if I run the app like 3-4 times, the app runs fine without any error.

Please help me with. I am stuck badly.

Sample Dataset :

UID invamt.base    duedate    gldate
1     200         12-02-19    05-01-19
2     300         15-03-19    01-02-19
3     200         12-02-19    02-02-19
4     300         12-02-19    19-02-19
5     400         15-03-19    12-02-19
6     200         17-04-19    16-02-19
7     100         17-04-19    19-02-19

This is what the dataset looks like:

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO :)  Please provide a reproducible example as it helps others to help you.  See this answer for guidance https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/1156245

Comment: Make sure that you are using `req()` for all the user input variables (input$abcs), and reactive dataframes prior to using them in the server side.